# Table rows show with button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need your advice with my code. 
First, I show code:

```js
$('tr:gt(9)').hide();
$('button.btn-primary').on('click', function() {
    var visible = $('tr:visible').length;
    $('tr:gt('+visible+')').slice(0,5).show();
})
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                <th>Producent</th>
                <th>Produkt</th>
                <th>Foto</th>
                <th>Typ</th>
                <th>Cena netto</th>
                <th>Cena brutto</th>
                <th>Interface</th>
                <th>Ilość dysków</th>
                <th>Pojemność</th>
                <th>RAID</th>
                <th>Wydajność</th>
                <th>Opis</th>
                <th>Specyfikacja</th>
                <th>Zakup</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
 
            <tbody class="results">
            <tr><td>G-Tech</td><td>vcxv</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/" style = "width:50px;height:50px;" alt="BRAK ZDJĘCIA"/></td><td>DAS Direct Attached Storage</td><td>50.00</td><td>70.00</td><td>USB 3.0</td><td>5</td><td>400</td><td>5*5*</td><td>500</td><td>dsadsad</td><td style='display:none;'>1</td><td><a href=http://www.o2.pl target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='34' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr><td>LaCie</td><td>Macierz</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/depositphotos_12071772-Website-Development-PHP-HTML-Arrows.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;" alt="BRAK ZDJĘCIA"/></td><td>SAN Srorage Area Network</td><td>98.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>miniSAS</td><td>6</td><td>4 TB</td><td>5</td><td>Duża</td><td>Tu powinien być opis, ale testuje i go nie wpisuje! </td><td style='display:none;'>2</td><td><a href=http://www.google.pl target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='36' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr><td>LaCie</td><td>dsad</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/IMG_20150504_074450.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;" alt="BRAK ZDJĘCIA"/></td><td>SAN Srorage Area Network</td><td>50.00</td><td>70.00</td><td>Thunderbolt</td><td>8</td><td>400</td><td>8/8/8</td><td>500</td><td>fasdf</td><td style='display:none;'>2</td><td><a href=http://fsdfsdf target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='37' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr><td>mLogic</td><td>test</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/ff.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;" alt="BRAK ZDJĘCIA"/></td><td>DAS Direct Attached Storage</td><td>80.00</td><td>100.00</td><td>Thunderbolt</td><td>8</td><td>900</td><td>5/8/8</td><td>600</td><td>fsdfd</td><td style='display:none;'>1</td><td><a href=http://fsdfds target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='38' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr><td>Promise</td><td>Zdjęcie</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/depositphotos_12071772-Website-Development-PHP-HTML-Arrows.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;" alt="BRAK ZDJĘCIA"/></td><td>DAS Direct Attached Storage</td><td>4564.00</td><td>999999.99</td><td>Thunderbolt</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>1</td><td>300</td><td>SPrawdzam czy działaja fotki .... .... .. .. .. .</td><td style='display:none;'>1</td><td><a href=http://feasd target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='39' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr><td>Promise</td><td>g</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/rc.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;" alt="BRAK ZDJĘCIA"/></td><td>DAS Direct Attached Storage</td><td>45.00</td><td>5.00</td><td>Thunderbolt</td><td>12</td><td>1</td><td>1</td><td>l</td><td>l</td><td style='display:none;'>1</td><td><a href=http://l target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='40' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr><td>Promise</td><td>jj</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/" style = "width:50px;height:50px;" alt="BRAK ZDJĘCIA"/></td><td>DAS Direct Attached Storage</td><td>1.00</td><td>1.00</td><td>Thunderbolt</td><td>2</td><td>j</td><td>j</td><td>j</td><td>n</td><td style='display:none;'>1</td><td><a href=http://j target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='43' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr><td>Promise</td><td>jj</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/" style = "width:50px;height:50px;" alt="BRAK ZDJĘCIA"/></td><td>DAS Direct Attached Storage</td><td>1.00</td><td>1.00</td><td>Thunderbolt</td><td>2</td><td>j</td><td>j</td><td>j</td><td>n</td><td style='display:none;'>1</td><td><a href=http://j target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='44' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr><td>G-Tech</td><td>Tesciowa</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/babcia xd.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;" alt="BRAK ZDJĘCIA"/></td><td>NAS Network Attached Storage</td><td>1.00</td><td>3.00</td><td>LAN</td><td>4</td><td>45</td><td>45</td><td>45</td><td>Chciałbym pozbyć się teściowej. Wredna babka ciągle ma jakieś problemy. </td><td style='display:none;'>2</td><td><a href=http://69 target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='45' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr><tr><td>LaCie</td><td>Macierz</td><td><img src="admin/forms/temp/depositphotos_12071772-Website-Development-PHP-HTML-Arrows.jpg" style = "width:50px;height:50px;" alt="BRAK ZDJĘCIA"/></td><td>SAN Srorage Area Network</td><td>98.00</td><td>120.00</td><td>miniSAS</td><td>6</td><td>4 TB</td><td>5</td><td>Duża</td><td>Tu powinien być opis, ale testuje i go nie wpisuje! </td><td style='display:none;'>2</td><td><a href=http://www.google.pl target='_blank'>Specyfikacja producenta</a></td><td><form action='' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='id' value='49' />
    <input class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' type='submit' name='koszykAdd' value='Dodaj do koszyka'/></form></td></tr>            </tbody>
            </table>   
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">
  Pokaż więcej
</button>
```

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc8nLtgr/)**</kbd>

**How it works:**

Load page = show 10 `<tr>`s. When the user click button (bottom), it shows 10 more rows but never show last. Do you know why and what have I to do with that problem? When the 9 is changing to 4, all works. Why?

Comment: This is because `:gt()` pseudo selector is: `Note that since JavaScript arrays use 0-based indexing, these selectors reflect that fact`. A naive fix would be: `var visible = $('tr:visible').length - 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code

```
var visible = $('tr:visible').length;
    $('tr:gt('+visible+')').slice(0,5).show();
```

You set the ‘visible’ initially to be 10 by

```
$('tr:gt(9)').hide();
```

So `$(‘tr:gt(10)’)` will return an empty array since it is selecting the `<tr>` tags from the 12th one and you only have 11th element.
To fix this, I recommend you change

```
var visible = $('tr:visible').length;
```

to

```
var visible = $('tr:visible').length - 1;
```

This problem is caused by the `$(“:gt(index)”)` selector. It looks like a css selector, which starts counting from 1. But it is actually a jQuery selector, which starts counting from 0.
I hope this can help. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It is because javascript arrays are zero index based. Meaning the first item in the array is index 0. `.length` will give you the number of items in the array but that number is 1 greater than the greatest index since the first is 0. I hope that make sense.

Try changing the `visible` variable to minus one.

```
var visible = $('tr:visible').length - 1;
```

To illustrate:

```
$('tr:visible')
```

would return an array as such

```
[
    <tr>...</tr>, // index 0
    <tr>...</tr>, // index 1
    <tr>...</tr>, // index 2
    <tr>...</tr>  // index 3
]
```

The length of the array is 4, but the greatest index is 3.

Then `:gt()` in jQuery goes based on `index` and not item number. So if I wanted item number 2 I would use index 1, :gt(1), that would return the second item in the array.